# How to see generated mysql string in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I am just wondering if there is a built in function to call if you want to get the generated mysql generated string in codeigniter. Consider the following example

```
$this->db->from('mytable');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I just wondering if there is `return $this->db->return_string()` that would result to

```
SELECT * FROM mytable blablablabla blablabla
```

I am scheming through out their site but seems cannot find what I am looking for.. any input guys?

Comment: sorry for the duplicate question guys but I had search on google about this question but I did not came up to that address, maybe I had the not mention the exact keywords on the search box.. it was okay now and thank you for the inputs ..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```